# How should multiple time formats be used?

Tags: formatting, datetime

I want to have a command to display the current time in a few different formats, specifically, the following:

- 2015-05-15
- 15 May 2015
- 122200
- 2015-05-15T122200

I'm not sure how to do this properly in LaTeX. I attempted the following:

```
\documentclass[american, a4paper]{report}

% time
% ISO date
    \usepackage[iso, inputamerican]{isodate}
% date formatting
    \usepackage{datetime}
    \newdateformat{timeA}{
        \THEYEAR-\twodigit{\THEMONTH}-\twodigit{\THEDAY}
    }
    \newdateformat{timeB}{
        \THEDAY~\monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR
    }
    \newtimeformat{timeC}{
        \twodigit{\THEHOUR}\twodigit{\THEMINUTE}\twodigit{\THESECOND}
    }
    \newdateformat{timeD}{
        \THEYEAR-\twodigit{\THEMONTH}-\twodigit{\THEDAY}T\timeC
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \timeA\today
\item \timeB\today
\item \timeC\today
\item \timeD\today
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

What I get when I compile this is the following:

- 2015-05-15
- 2015-05-15
- 1222002015-05-15
- 2015-05-15

What should I change? Is there a better way to approach this?

---

Following [a suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245116/how-should-multiple-time-formats-be-used?noredirect=1#comment582570_245116) by @Grimler, I removed the package `isodate`. This is a step in the right direction and produces the following result:

- 2015-05-15
- 15 May 2015
- 122200 15 May 2015
- 2015-05-15T 122200

So, what it would be good to know now is how to print the third one correctly (i.e. without the date) -- should simply setting the format actually print something? -- and how to remove the space between the `T` and the time in the fourth one.

Comment: FYI: package `datetime` got obsolete a little while back and the moden package `datetime2` can be used.

Comment: Removing the isodate package gives the result you want. I guess the two packages don't play well together.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for that. I'll give it a try. Would you happen to know how to install this in Ubuntu 15.04?

Comment: @Grimler Thanks for that. It's certainly a step in the right direction. It doesn't produce exactly the correct output -- I've detailed this in the edit above. If you have any ideas about how to think about how the *formatting* step is printing something and if you have any ideas about how to remove that space between the ```T``` and the time, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand why, but if you remove the `\today` on the third itemize row, you get rid of the date but keep the time (`\item \timeC` instead of `\item \timeC\today`)

As for the space after the T, simply change the `\timeC` definition to:

```
\newtimeformat{timeC}{%
\twodigit{\THEHOUR}\twodigit{\THEMINUTE}\twodigit{\THESECOND}
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much for your assistance.